# Android Camera Preview not Full Screen

Tags: android, camera, fullscreen, preview

I am developing a camera app but the camera is not full screen. I am using common "CameraPreview" class  to open camera. it includes Surfaceview and Determining Optimal Size for camera. In tablet and phones, camera is not full screen. For example, tablet size is 1280x728 but camera size is 1024x768. It is shown in FrameLayout for which layout widht and height is FillParent. I could not understand and solve this issue. I wanna open camera in full screen without stretching.

Is there anybody got this issue and fix it?

Comment: Judging by the code here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java (which you can use actually), you can use the method `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` and see what are the supported resolutions, 1024x768 could easily be the highest one available for this preview.

Comment: I determine the size by the method you offer but it returns 2 size for tablet, 640x480 and 1024x768. No highest one available.

Comment: Yes, so those are the supported resolutions, there's no way you can get higher than the supported. You must find a workaround for this, like to put the preview in the center and surrond it with black frame or something like that. I guees the suggestion can now be considered as a correct answer to the question?

Comment: Yes it can be considered as correct answer if there is no another way for this issue.

Comment: Well, I'll paste it as an answer, you decide it, but believe me, you can't get higher than the supported preview.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging by the code [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java):(which you can use actually), you can use the method `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` and see what are the supported resolutions, `1024x768` could easily be the highest one available for this preview and as you found out, it is really the highest supported.

So those are the supported resolutions, there's no way you can get higher than the supported. You must find a workaround for this, like to put the preview in the center and surrond it with black frame or something like that.